# Msbulid is not displayed in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

i am trying to use continuous integration by using jenkins with svn for bulid a .net code.

For that i installed msbuild plugin.but the msbulid plugin is not displayed in jenkins configuration( Jenkins » Manage Jenkins » Configure System.)

but it is installed..

Comment: I am having this problem as well with the latest version, I think they moved the configuration

Answer (score 0):

This has been moved to the Global Tool Configuration under manage jenkins on version 2.7.1